# Qt Missing compiler for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, qt5

I am trying to setup Qt so that I can build & deploy from my Windows 10 machine, to an Android tablet.

However from Tools>Options>Kits>Qt Versions... I get "No compiler can produce code for this Qt version.  Please define one or more compilers for x86-linux-android-elf-32bit".

(or instead of 'x86-linux...' it says 'arm-linux-android-elf-32bi't or 'arm-linux-android-elf-64bit', depending on the Qt version I have selected in this window).

Do I need to manually add C and C++ compilers for the Android SDK/NDK to Qt?  Where would I find these?

**I have installed:**

- Qt:  5.12.0
- Qt Creator:  4.7.0 (Community)
- Android SDK:  3.2.1 64-bit Windows.
- Android NDK:  r18b Windows 64-bit.
- Java JDK:  Java SE Development Kit 8u191

**From Qt Maintenance tool, Installed Qt 5.12.0 for Android x86, ARM64-v8a, ARMv7:**

[image: Qt Maintenance Tool Installed Components - screen shot]

**Within Qt Creator Tools>Options>Devices>Android I have set the paths of the JDK, SDK, & NDK and run "Update Installed":**
[image: Qt Creator>Tools>Options>Devices>Android - screen shot]

**If I go to Tools>Options>Kits>Qt Versions I see several versions, each is missing a compiler** (compiler varies based on version):
[image: Qt Creator>Tools>Options>Kits>Qt Versions screen shot]

**But in Compilers, here is all I see:**
[image: Qt Creator>Tools>Options>Kits>Compilers - screen shot]

**In looking through the NDK I did see these, are these related to what I am looking for?:**
[image: \Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin - screen shot]

Comment: I confronted myself with a similar problem only in the armv8-a context (qt 5.13 beta 4). The solution was to update my QtCreator alongside the new qt.

Answer (score 1):

When I update my QtCreator(community) from 4.7.1 to 4.9.1, everything is ok.